# Some Meta questions have had [status-review] since 2014

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, stack-exchange

I recently filtered on the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag and noticed that there are nearly 150 questions tagged that way, some of which are quite old (the oldest being from 2014, which was 8 years ago as of today). This makes it hard for me as a user to tell what the actual status of them is.

Is there any chance that SE can clean this up at some point so that we can have more visibility into which proposals they're actually actively working on?

Comment: Amusingly, on Friday JNat and I just went through a list of all the status-review posts (that were tagged prior to the system pulling those posts into Jira automagically) network-wide to split up between different teams to assess and update the status (if appropriate). Lots of the ones here on MSO are related to defunct products like dev story and docs, so we'll just be removing the tags.

Comment: @Catija Excellent, thanks. That'll make it easier for us to see which Meta posts SE is still actively working on and which ones have been completed, declined, or otherwise abandoned, which would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going through the older [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) posts not only on MSO but across the whole Stack Exchange Network was a recent backlog smash that several members of the Product and Community Management teams took on over the past few months. We've updated the statuses on these posts so the community is able to see which ones we'll be picking up in the near future. [I wrote more details about this effort on Meta Stack Exchange.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386681/ticket-smash-for-status-review-tag-part-deux)

Comment: Okay, technically they no longer go back to 2014 - they now [only go back to 2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-review?tab=newest&page=3&pagesize=50).

Comment: This reminded me of https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUfAs.jpg ... (the [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/stackoverflow/comments/c6sw60/community_managers_explain_how_they_manage_stack/)) probably in poor taste, but still found it funny, sorry! :D